# Unable to Parse a date of format d MMMM yyyy in Polish Locale in Java

Tags: java, date, locale, date-format, polish

I tried to parse the date (3 December, 2020) with format d MMMM yyyy in Polish Locale but it is unable to parse. But why the same parsing is working fine in any other locale like english, etc. Below is the code sample which is not working. Can anyone please help on this ?

```
    Locale loc = new Locale("pl", "PL");
    String date = "3 December 2020";
    SimpleDateFormat sdFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", loc);
    sdFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date d = sdFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing date in polish locale in Joda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723987/parsing-date-in-polish-locale-in-joda)

Comment: December may not be recognized in Polish, try changing to 12 and use MM

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got confused with **parsing** and **formatting**.

Since your input date string in `English`, you need to use `Locale.ENGLISH` **for parsing** and you need another instance of `SimpleDateFormat` with `Locale("pl", "PL")` **to format** the obtained `java.util.Date` object with `new Locale("pl", "PL")`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Locale loc = new Locale("pl", "PL");
        String date = "3 December 2020";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfForParsing = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfForFormatting = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", loc);
        sdfForParsing.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date d = sdfForParsing.parse(date);
            System.out.println(d);
            String localiseByPolish = sdfForFormatting.format(d);
            System.out.println(localiseByPolish);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thu Dec 03 00:00:00 GMT 2020
3 grudnia 2020
```

I believe you already know that a date-time object stores just the date-time information<sup>*1</sup>and **no formatting information**. On printing, a date-time object prints the string returned by the `toString` implementation of its class. Also, a `java.util.Date` object **does not represent a true date-time class** as it stores just the milliseconds (e.g. `new Date()` object is instantiated with the number of milliseconds from  `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`) and when you print it, it calculates the date-time in your JVM's timezone and prints the same i.e. if your execute the following two lines at a given moment in any part of the world,

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

you will get the same number. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727157/10819573) for a demo.

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and because of so many such hacks, they are error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Locale loc = new Locale("pl", "PL");
        String date = "3 December 2020";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfForParsing = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfForFormatting = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy", loc);
        LocalDate localeDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dtfForParsing);
        System.out.println(localeDate);
        String localiseByPolish = localeDate.format(dtfForFormatting);
        System.out.println(localiseByPolish);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-03
3 grudnia 2020
```

---

<sup>*1The [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) store also the timezone information. Check [Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) to learn more about these classes.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

When trying to determine problems with parsing, always do the opposite, i.e. generate output, to see what the input for parsing should look like. This is a technique that is very useful for all parsing related issues, whether parsing date strings, XML documents, JSON texts, etc.

So, we try *printing* a date value with the given format, to see what it would expect when parsing:

```java
Locale loc = new Locale("pl", "PL");
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", loc);
sdFormat.setLenient(false);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(loc);
cal.clear();
cal.set(2020, Calendar.DECEMBER, 3);
System.out.println(sdFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

In Java 7, I get `3 grudzień 2020`.
In Java 8, 9, 11, and 14, I get `3 grudnia 2020`.

If you want to parse `3 December 2020`, then use e.g. `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: OP has specifically mentioned `"3 December 2020"` as the date string to be processed. Why are you suggesting to change the problem to align it with your solution?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Please read the answer. Now read last line again. If OP want `"3 December 2020"` to parse, then OP cannot use Polish locale, but must use e.g. English locale, and *that's the only code change suggested* by this answer. --- The rest is guidance for how to **research** the problem, so OP can decide what to do about it. It's often very difficult to fix a problem if you don't understand how it is wrong. This helps you figure out how/why it is failing.